# Android BLE device scan with device name filter is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am using device name filter to connect to a specific BLE device. But my scan call back is not executing. It works fine when I use MAC address as filter. Is this a known issue or bug? I am testing on Asus Tablet with Android 6.0. As I am reading the scan filter to be used from a device name database, I do not have an alternative to use MAC address.

//This does not work

```
    ScanFilter scanFilter = (new android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter.Builder())
.setDeviceName(device_name).build();
```

//This works

```
ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                                    .setDeviceAddress(dev_mac_address).build();
```

Comment: Same here. UUID works, device name ... nope